# Why can't we grind beyond level 20 in Fallout 3?

Tags: fallout-3

I'm asking because it's becoming increasingly difficult to deal with Death claws and I really want to experiment on various other perks.
Does it have something to do with the story?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

20 is the forced cap on levelling for Fallout 3.

It can be expanded to level 30 by purchasing the [Broken Steel](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Broken_Steel) DLC.

As for dealing with Deathclaws,

> get crafting the [Dart Gun](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Dart_gun) and immobilise them from afar.

Comment: ah,I've been assuming the Dart gun to be an ineffective weapon, thanks!

Comment: It's not about the damage. It cripples limbs - particularly legs - so that the enemy can't run after you. After paralysing, switch to your blaster of choice.

Comment: oh, I'll keep that in mind.

Comment: And hang on to your fat boys for them specifically. I <3 that little guy.

Comment: I am very conservative when it comes to them mini nukes - I prefer energy weapons.

Comment: The only problem with being conservative with the Fat Boys is - when to use them! I realised I was stockpiling them for a rainy day and they lay unused in my house. So I created a rainy day.

Comment: Yea, I never really thought about when to use them. The last time I used it, it was against that giant super mutant near GNR (at the very beginning of my 65 hour play through). After that, no where else.